# Why can I minimize the surface area of a three-dimensional object, if I calculate its Derivative and set it to 0?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am looking for an explanation regarding this Math Problem:

> An open-topped glass aquarium with a square base is designed to hold 4
> cubic feet of water. What is the minimum exterior surface area of the
> aquarium?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DpS6.jpg)

**Please explain to me why I need to find the derivative of the Surface Area, set it equal to zero, and solve the resulting equation, to minimize the surface area?**

I just don't understand this logic..
The Derivative of the Surface Area represents the Rate of Change of the Surface Area...why does this help me find the minimum surface area for that specified volume?

**I don't need your help for resolving this problem. I know the answer to it, but I don't understand the logic behind yet.

Answer (score 1):

When we have a function that represents the surface area of the aquarium, such as:

$A(s, h) = s^2 + 4sh$

We want to minimize this function subject to the constraint that the volume is 4 cubic feet:

$V(s, h) = s^2h = 4$

We can use the volume constraint equation to express one of the variables in terms of the other. For example, we can solve for h in terms of s:

$h = 4/s^2$

Substituting this expression for h into the surface area function, we get a new function of one variable, s:

$A(s) = s^2 + 16/s$

To find the minimum value of A(s), we take the derivative of A(s) with respect to s:

$A'(s) = 2s - 16/s^2$

Setting A'(s) equal to zero gives us the critical point(s) of the function where the slope is zero. We can then test these critical points to see if they correspond to a minimum or maximum point. In this case, we have:

$2s - 16/s^2 = 0$

Solving for s, we get:

$s^3 = 8$

$s = 2$

We can then substitute this value of s back into the volume constraint equation to solve for h:

$h = 4/s^2 = 1/2$

Therefore, the minimum surface area of the aquarium is:

$A(2, 1/2) = 2^2 + 4(2)(1/2) = 12$ square feet.

The reason why we take the derivative of the surface area function and set it equal to zero is because the derivative tells us the slope of the function at any point. If the slope is positive, the function is increasing. If the slope is negative, the function is decreasing. The critical points where the derivative is zero correspond to points where the slope changes from positive to negative or negative to positive, which can be a minimum or maximum point. By testing these critical points, we can determine whether they correspond to a minimum or maximum point, and therefore find the minimum surface area of the aquarium.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @Laxo If you could mark the question as answered if it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the minimum surface area, making any change in the dimensions will increase the surface area: whether you increase or decrease your chosen parameter you will get an increase in the surface area.

Imagine the graph of the function at that point - if it is smooth, and rises on each side, it has a minimum point at which the tangent is horizontal. You are right that the derivative gives the rate of change - a horizontal tangent implies a rate of change (and hence a derivative) of zero.

In problems like this you need to take care that the zero derivative gives the kind of answer you want - it could be a maximum or a minimum, or (perhaps rarely) an inflection ($y=x^3$ at $x=0$, for example) - so you need to check that.

Setting an optimisation problem up in such a way that it can be solved by setting a derivative equal to zero is the beginning of a set of techniques which come in surprisingly useful, especially in multi-dimensional situations.